# Youtube flash object in page causes (mobile) safari to crash

Tags: iphone, flash, youtube, safari

I have a lot of pages (thousands) with user generated content containing Youtube video's embedded with flash objects. This content was generated by a rich text editor like CKeditor and TinyMCE. They look like this:

```
<object width="550" height="400" data="//www.youtube.com/v/hENGl-ebqp0?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="internal" /><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/hENGl-ebqp0?version=3" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" /></object>
```

I can't replace this with the iframe/html5 version of youtube embeds because this is part of larger pieces of HTML saved in a database.

But pages using these flash youtube embeds crash in Safari on iPhone. The page tries to reload a few times and end in a crash message.

This is a sample page which crashes in Safari: http://www.badboysbrand.nl/c-3021388/video/

Comment: On which iOS you are testing?

Comment: The latest, 9.2.1, but the issue exists since july 2015.